# Show status when data in database MySQL was deleted in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I have issue when showing the status when data was delete or not. Here's the code

```
 public bool isDelete (String nim, String pass)
    {
        String query = "delete from dbmahasiswa where NIM=@NIM AND Password=@Password";
        class_Mahasiswa cm = new class_Mahasiswa();
        try
        {
            connect.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connect);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NIM", nim);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", pass);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MySqlDataReader reader;
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            int count = 0;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                count += 1;
            }
            if (count == 1)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("sukses!", "Status");
                return true;
            }
            else
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("akun tidak ditemukan", "Status");
            return false;
            connect.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Warning");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

If I type the wrong username or password, it will show MessageBox "akun tidak ditemukan"(account not found). Also when I type the right username and password to delete it, it will show that MessageBox because the function will read the database after data has been deleted.

My question is, how to show the "Sukses" MessageBox when data has been deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling *ExecuteReader*. The *ExecuteReader* is used to read data returning from the query with a SELECT statement. You can't use it to know if a row or more has been deleted. For this task you use just *ExecuteNonQuery* and get the return value to know the number of rows 'affected' by the query command

```
    String query = "delete from dbmahasiswa where NIM=@NIM AND Password=@Password";
    class_Mahasiswa cm = new class_Mahasiswa();
    try
    {
        connect.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connect);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NIM", nim);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", pass);
        int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (rows > 0)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("sukses!", "Status");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("akun tidak ditemukan", "Status");
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Warning");
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        connect.Close();
    }
}
```

Also, it seems that you are using a global *connect* object for your connection. This is usually the source of many bugs like the one you have in your catch clause. If your code results in an exception you forgot to close the connection and, in the next call to *connect.Open*, you will get an error. I have added a *finally* to ensure proper closure of your connection object. However it is a better practice to keep the connection local to the code where you need it, open inside a using statement block to have it closed and disposed at the end of the block

Comment: I wouldn't show a MessageBox in a function called isDelete(). Only return true or false in a boolean function.

Comment: I agree with you. Hope they are there just to follow the code flow albeit using a debugger is the only good method.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Steve your code works nicely. And thank you for your explanation, it will help me a lot